# cannot load such file -- shoulda/context (LoadError) error ruby 1.9 rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I am getting this error when trying to run or migrate my rails app.

> ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/shoulda-3.4.0/lib/shoulda.rb:3:in `require':
>   cannot load such file -- shoulda/context (LoadError)

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION :** sudo chmod -R 755 $GEM_HOME/gems/shoulda-context-1.0.2

seems like a permission error.
I found the solution finally on a teamtreehouse forum by Jason Stiegler

Comment: Make sure you don't use `sudo` when running `bundle install`. That is a common cause of permission problems.